# Installing Xamp apache failed because Oracle port

Tags: oracle, apache, oracle11g, xampp

I have installed Xampp, but when I try to start Apache it says that The Apache cannot start because the port 80 is already in use by Sql Oracle , try to delete the application wich use that port. How can I fix it? Is there a way to change the port of the xamp or is it something else?

The version of Oracle is 11g and version of xampp is 5.6.3-0-VC11.

Comment: change `Listen 80`to `Listen 1234`  will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop Apache if already running.

Go to `C:\xampp\apache\conf`

Open `httpd.conf`using notepad or any other editor.

Change the listener to another port like

`Listen 80` to `Listen 1234`

Start The apache , it will work.